# Requiring SOAP - Node JS package fails with an import error in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, npm, soap, aws-lambda

My Lambda function is running on Node JS 10.x. Tried requiring the soap npm module but it fails with the following error.

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'soap'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'soap'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}
```

Tried looking in several threads but no luck. The file name is index.js and the handler name is index.handler if that information helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the folder structure and dependencies set up. Since 'soap' module is an additional package which is out of the libraries in the AWS SDK for JavaScript. I install it locally with npm and included it in the deployment package. Then updated the Lambda function using AWS SDK.

Refer this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#nodejs-package-dependencies